# How to access contents of a TLorentz vector using python code

Tags: python, uproot

I am using the `uproot` package in python to read a .root file, and I need to access the contents of `pf`. As you can see from the picture, I can easily access the content of `vz` (blue arrows). However, when accessing the contents of `pf` (red arrows), it gives me an error. Based on the middle column in the description table, I realize that they different objects. Nevertheless, my question is, how can I access the objects of `pf`? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Also, please let me know if you cannot access the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SjdO.png)[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited my post and added another image with more code. Hopefully, that is better.

Comment: This is a data type that should be readable. The fact that it isn't being read is either a corrupted file or a bug in Uproot. StackOverflow is best for how-to questions, but bugs should be reported in GitHub Issues. Be sure to include a downloadable copy of the file and the complete error message. This image doesn't show the message: in Python, the most relevant part of an error message is the last line, not the first line. Thanks!